# Does Maple 15 use parallel computing for integrating?

Tags: maple

Maple 15 has a new feature, using all cores at the same time. But this is for the `expand` function which I saw [on their official site](http://www.maplesoft.com/products/maple/new_features/auto_parallelism.aspx).

Is this for all commands or `expand` only? Because I tried with integrating and saw that just one core worked.

Comment: Same comment [as here](http://superuser.com/questions/315337/how-to-make-commands-in-mathematica-8-use-all-cores)

Answer (score 1):

The relevant part of that page is

> "to perform many computations in parallel."

Many !=all.